# How to customize the default scrollbar on the pdf document?

Tags: html, css, pdf

How can I customize the default scrollbar that browser shows on pdf file?

```
<object data="/pdf/sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
   <p><b>Example fallback content</b>: This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="/pdf/sample.pdf">Download PDF</a>.</p>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear which scroll bar you're talking about. Is it part of the browser or part of the PDF viewer? More importantly: Which browser and viewer are you using?

Suppose you're using Adobe's PDF viewer, then you can add an argument to the url like this:

`data="/pdf/sample.pdf?scrollbar=0"`

See: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

This can however have no effect when using other pdf viewers. More so, the scroll bars are often there for a good reason.

Activating touch mode can also remove the scroll bar in some viewers.

Basically you don't have much control over this.

Your real question is about customization. This could mean a lot of things, for instance making the scroll bar wider, changing its color, etc. Clearly this cannot be easily done when the scroll bar is part of the viewer.

Lastly, the message; 'This browser does not support PDFs.', is not entirely accurate. It will also be shown if the PDF file doesn't exist.

EDIT:

This works to get rid of the extra scroll bar in Chrome:

```
<html>
<body style="overflow:hidden;margin:0">
<object data="sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
   <p>Error!</p>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am asking for default pdf viewer in web browser like chrome, mozilla etc. How to customize the scrollbar that they add on pdf doc. When the above code is previewed in browser there are two scrollbars 1. First on container of pdf  2. Second on whole window ( the webpage scrollbar )

Comment: You're out of luck then, parameter support of these viewers is very sketchy. You should not get two scroll bars in the same direction. If you use chrome you can hide its scroll bar with a style: `body { overflow: hidden; margin:0; }`